# Claims missing after redirect to Angular App

Tags: angular, identityserver4, openid-connect

We have set up an Identity Server to use for all of our authentication and authorizations.  We have been following most examples online but maybe we are missing something.

I am sharing everything below but if you need to see something else, just ask.

Expected flow/behaviour:

1. User goes to Web App (Angular)
2. Web App determines if the user is authenticated, if not redirects to Auth Server
3. Auth Server does what it does and user ends up at the Login page
4. User Logs in
5. If the login is successful, Auth Service logs in the user and assigns claims to Identity.
6. Auth Server redirects back to Web App
7. Web App should be able to see claims in the token, specifically looking for `organization_id` and `organization_short_name`

Actual flow/behaviour:
 1. User goes to Web App (Angular)
 2. Web App determines if the user is authenticated, if not redirects to Auth Server
 3. Auth Server does what it does and user ends up at the Login page
 4. User Logs in
 5. If the login is successful, Auth Service logs in the user and assigns claims to Identity. (have verified this)
 6. Auth Server redirects back to Web App
 7. Web App can only see standard claims (see below)

As I have **AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken** set as true, I would expect all the user claims to come across.

I also want to point out that I did have response_type set to `id_token token` but had the same result as now with just `id_token`.  The return provided the access (bearer) token.

**Returned Claims**

```
{"sid":"a994edfc711e0729e133acbcc9cde367","sub":"6f1803fc-125e-4920-557d-08d695d06a94","auth_time":1551446274,"idp":"local","username":"me@example.com","role":"Support","amr":["pwd"]}
```

**AccountsController.cs**

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpPost("login", Name = nameof(PostLogin))]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostLogin(LoginViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await _memberManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.UserName);

        if (user != null && !await _memberManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user))
        {
            if (await _memberManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
            {
                if (!await _memberManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user))
                {
                    await _memberManager.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(user);

                    if (await _memberManager.GetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(user))
                    {
                        _logger.LogInformation(
                            "Login attempt for `{username}` successful but has 2FA/2SA Enabled.",
                            user.UserName);
                        var validProviders = await _memberManager.GetValidTwoFactorProvidersAsync(user);
                        if (validProviders.Contains(_memberManager.Options.Tokens.AuthenticatorTokenProvider))
                        {
                            //await HttpContext.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme)
                        }
                    }


                    if (user.Organizations.Count == 0)
                    {
                        // TODO : Build Page to inform member they have not associated organizations
                    }
                    else if (user.Organizations.Count > 1)
                    {
                        // TODO : Build Page to let member select organization they want to login into
                    }

                    _claimsPrincipalFactory.Organization = user.Organizations.FirstOrDefault()?.Organization;

                    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
                    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);
                    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityServerConstants.DefaultCookieAuthenticationScheme);

                    var principal = await _claimsPrincipalFactory.CreateAsync(user);
                    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, principal);

                    //var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password,
                    //    model.RememberMe, true);

                    await _memberManager.RecordLoginAttempt(user.Id, LoginStatusType.Success);
                    _logger.LogInformation("Login attempt for `{username}` successful.", user.UserName);
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.ReturnUrl)) return View("UserClaims");
                    return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
                }

                await _memberManager.RecordLoginAttempt(user.Id, LoginStatusType.Failure);
                _logger.LogInformation("Login attempt for `{username}` but email is unconfirmed.",
                    user.UserName);
                ModelState.AddModelError("", _localizer["UnconfirmedEmail"]);
            }
            else
            {
                await _memberManager.RecordLoginAttempt(user.Id, LoginStatusType.Failure);
                await _memberManager.AccessFailedAsync(user);

                if (await _memberManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user))
                    _logger.LogInformation(
                        "Login attempt for `{username}` but account is locked out until {lockout}",
                        user.UserName, user.LockoutEnd);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("Login attempt for unknown username: {username}", model.UserName);
            ModelState.AddModelError("", _localizer["InvalidUsernameOrPassword"]);
        }
    }

    return View("Login", model);
}
```

**MemberClaimsPrinciplaFactory.cs**

```
public class MemberClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<Member>
    {
        private readonly MemberManager _memberManager;
        private readonly OrganizationRoleManager _organizationRoleManager;

        public MemberClaimsPrincipalFactory(MemberManager userManager,
            OrganizationRoleManager organizationRoleManager,
            IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
            : base(userManager, optionsAccessor)
        {
            _memberManager = userManager;
            _organizationRoleManager = organizationRoleManager;
        }

        public Organization Organization { get; set; }

        #region Overrides of UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<Member>

        public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(Member user)
        {
            if (user == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));
            var id = await GenerateClaimsAsync(user);
            return new ClaimsPrincipal(id);
        }

        #endregion

        protected async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateClaimsAsync(Member user)
        {
            if (Organization == null) throw new NullReferenceException("Organization must have value.");

            var identity = await base.GenerateClaimsAsync(user);

            // Add Organization Details
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("organization_id", Organization.Id.ToString()));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("organization_short_name", Organization.ShortName));

            // Add Username
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("username", user.UserName));

            // Adding Role(s) and Role Claim(s)
            var roleIds = await _memberManager.GetOrganizationRoleIds(user);
            foreach (var roleId in roleIds)
            {
                var orgRole = await _organizationRoleManager.GetRoleById(Organization.Id, roleId);
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", orgRole.Name));
                var roleClaims = await _organizationRoleManager.GetClaimsByRoleId(orgRole.Id);
                identity.AddClaims(roleClaims);
            }


            // Adding Member Claim(s)
            var claims = await _memberManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
            foreach (var claim in claims)
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(claim.Type.ToLower(), claim.Value));


            return identity;
        }
    }
```

**Client (DB Record)**
[image: Client (DB Record)]

**Identity Resource (DB Record)**
[image: Identity Resource (DB Record)]

**.well-known/openid-configuration**

```
{
  issuer: "http://localhost:5000",
  jwks_uri: "http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks",
  authorization_endpoint: "http://localhost:5000/connect/authorize",
  token_endpoint: "http://localhost:5000/connect/token",
  userinfo_endpoint: "http://localhost:5000/connect/userinfo",
  end_session_endpoint: "http://localhost:5000/connect/endsession",
  check_session_iframe: "http://localhost:5000/connect/checksession",
  revocation_endpoint: "http://localhost:5000/connect/revocation",
  introspection_endpoint: "http://localhost:5000/connect/introspect",
  device_authorization_endpoint: "http://localhost:5000/connect/deviceauthorization",
  frontchannel_logout_supported: true,
  frontchannel_logout_session_supported: true,
  backchannel_logout_supported: true,
  backchannel_logout_session_supported: true,
  scopes_supported: [
    "openid",
    "email",
    "profile",
    "organization",
    "auth-api",
    "offline_access"
  ],
  claims_supported: [
    "sub",
    "email_verified",
    "email",
    "zoneinfo",
    "birthdate",
    "gender",
    "website",
    "picture",
    "profile",
    "locale",
    "preferred_username",
    "middle_name",
    "given_name",
    "family_name",
    "name",
    "nickname",
    "updated_at",
    "organization_id",
    "organization_short_name"
  ],
  grant_types_supported: [
    "authorization_code",
    "client_credentials",
    "refresh_token",
    "implicit",
    "password",
    "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code"
  ],
  response_types_supported: [
    "code",
    "token",
    "id_token",
    "id_token token",
    "code id_token",
    "code token",
    "code id_token token"
  ],
  response_modes_supported: [
    "form_post",
    "query",
    "fragment"
  ],
  token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported: [
    "client_secret_basic",
    "client_secret_post"
  ],
  subject_types_supported: [
    "public"
  ],
  id_token_signing_alg_values_supported: [
    "RS256"
  ],
  code_challenge_methods_supported: [
    "plain",
    "S256"
  ]
}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { UserManager, UserManagerSettings, User } from 'oidc-client';
import { fail } from 'assert';

import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { UserProfile } from '../models/userprofile';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private manager: UserManager = new UserManager(getClientSettings());
  private user: User = null;

  constructor() {
    this.manager.getUser().then(user => {
      this.user = user;
    });

    //console.log("auth.service.constructor.user=" + this.user);
    //https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/wiki

    //EVENTS - begin
    this.manager.events.addSilentRenewError(function (e) {
      console.log("silent renew error", e.message);
    });

    this.manager.events.addAccessTokenExpired(function () {
      if (environment.debug_mode) {
        console.log("token has expired...");
      }
      //creates a loop
      //window.location.href = "/logoff/";
    });

    this.manager.events.addUserLoaded(function () {
      if (environment.debug_mode) {
        console.log("user has been loaded, redirect to cases...");
      }

      window.location.href = "/cases/";
    });
    //EVENTS - end


  }

  isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return this.user != null && !this.user.expired;
  }

  getUser(): any {
    return this.user;
  }

  isUserExpired(): boolean {
    if (this.user != null)
      return this.user.expired
    else
      return true;
  }

  getAccessToken(): string {
    return this.user.access_token;
  }

  getTokenType(): string {
    return this.user.token_type;
  }

  getClaims(): any {
    return this.user.profile;
  }

  getScopes(): any {
    return this.user.scopes;
  }

  startAuthentication(): Promise<void> {
    return this.manager.signinRedirect();
  }

  completeAuthentication(): Promise<void> {
    return this.manager.signinRedirectCallback().then(user => {
      this.user = user;
    });
  }

  hasPermission(permission: string, category: string, subcategory: string): boolean {

    let rtn: boolean = false;

    if (this.user != null) {

      let userProfile: UserProfile = this.getClaims();

      let claim: string = category + "__" + subcategory;

      let profile: string = userProfile[claim];

      if (profile == undefined) {
        return false;
      }

      if (environment.debug_mode) {
        //console.log("hasPermission, profile: " + profile);
      }

      if (profile.includes(permission)) {
        rtn = true;
      }
    }

    return rtn;
  }

  logout(): Promise<void> {

    return this.manager.signoutRedirect();

  }
}

export function getClientSettings(): UserManagerSettings {
  return {
    authority: environment.auth_authority,
    client_id: environment.auth_client_id,
    redirect_uri: environment.auth_redirect_uri,
    post_logout_redirect_uri: environment.auth_post_logout_redirect_uri,
    response_type: "id_token",
    scope: environment.auth_scope,
    filterProtocolClaims: true,
    loadUserInfo: true
    //metadata: {
    //  issuer: environment.auth_authority.substring(0, environment.auth_authority.length - 1),
    //  jwks_uri: environment.auth_authority + '.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks',
    //  end_session_endpoint: environment.auth_authority + 'connect/endsession',
    //  authorization_endpoint: environment.auth_authority + 'connect/authorize',
    //  userinfo_endpoint: environment.auth_authority + 'connect/userinfo'
    //}
    //automaticSilentRenew: true,
    //silent_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/silent-refresh.html'
  };
}
```

**environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  debug_mode: true,
  version: "{VERSION}",
  auth_authority: (<any>window)._env.auth_authority,
  auth_redirect_uri: (<any>window)._env.auth_redirect_uri,
  auth_post_logout_redirect_uri: (<any>window)._env.auth_post_logout_redirect_uri,
  auth_client_id: "ui-web-app",
  auth_scope: "openid organization",

  //APIs.
  oc_api_members_url: "api/members/",
  oc_api_appointments_url: "api/appointments/",
  oc_api_centers_url: "api/centers/",
  oc_api_organizations_url: "api/organizations/",
  oc_api_procedure_protocols_url: "api/procedureprotocols/",
  auth_api_organizations_url: "api/organizations/"

};
```

**appConfig.json**

```
{
    "auth_authority":  "http://localhost:5000/",
    "auth_redirect_uri":  "http://localhost:4200/auth-callback",
    "auth_post_logout_redirect_uri":  "http://localhost:4200/",
}
```

**env.js**

```
window._env = {
    auth_authority: 'http://localhost:5000/',
    auth_redirect_uri: "http://localhost:4200/auth-callback",
    auth_post_logout_redirect_uri: "http://localhost:4200/",
   };
```

Comment: Did you override the DefaultProfileService in IdentityServer with a custom ProfileService?

Comment: We have extended the Profile Service and we can get claims back from calling `/connect/userinfo` but this opens up a different issue.  A user can belong to more than one organization and could have different roles, including different claims, depending on which organization they sign in under.  We cannot find a way to filter down the claims via the userinfo end-point to only use the organization they signed in under.

Comment: Can you verify the context is UserInfoEndpoint and that the claims are added to that context's IssuedClaims collection?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg Yes I can confirm when we call the userinfo end point we are assigning claims to the issuedclaims collection but we do not know which organization the user signed in under at this point so we cannot assign org specific roles (and their claims)

Comment: @RuardvanElburg Sorry, I have been really busy.  We did actually figure it out after having several eyes look it over.  Turns out that someone has mistyped a few things, mainly the scopes requested (which should have thrown an error) and the actual Identity Resource names in the DB.  After a bit of cleanup and flushing the DB everything started to work as expected.